# Send many BITOP in a single atomic operation using ioredis

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm using the ioredis client (@4.6.2) with node.js and i need to do a lot of bit operations (which are not depending on each other). Something like this :

```
import * as ioredis from "ioredis";

...

private readonly client: ioredis.Redis;
this.client = new ioredis("my_url");

...

await this.client.send_command("BITOP", "OR", "a_or_b", "a", "b");
await this.client.send_command("BITOP", "OR", "a_or_c", "a", "c");
await this.client.send_command("BITOP", "OR", "a_or_d", "a", "d");
await this.client.send_command("BITOP", "OR", "a_or_e", "a", "e");
// etc...
```

With some other operations (such as `setbit`), I can use the *pipeline* object and its `exec()` function to run them atomically :

```
const pipeline: Pipeline = this.client.pipeline();
pipeline.setbit(a, 1, 1);
pipeline.setbit(a, 12, 0);
pipeline.setbit(b, 3,  1);
await pipeline.exec();
```

But I can't find any `pipeline.bitop()` nor `pipeline.send_command()` function.

Is there any way to send these `BITOP` commands in an atomic operation ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to do it, using an array of commands as parameters to the constructor (as described in ioredis documentation), and it's way faster !

```
const result: number[][] = await this.redis.pipeline([
      ["bitop", "OR", "a_or_b", "a", "b"],
      ["bitop", "OR", "a_or_c", "a", "c"],
      ["bitop", "OR", "a_or_d", "a", "d"],
      ...

      ["bitcount", "a_or_b"],
      ["bitcount", "a_or_c"],
      ["bitcount", "a_or_d"],
      ...
]).exec();
```